# Differences between ViewCompositionStrategy in Jetpack Compose interop

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What are the differences between the `ViewCompositionStrategy` in Jetpack compose when it comes to using `Compose View` in XML?

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#composition-strategy
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/ViewCompositionStrategy

What `ViewCompositionStrategy` is needed when:

1. `<ComposeView>` in an activity layout
2. `<ComposeView>` in a fragment layout
3. `<ComposeView>` in a custom view which is in a fragment (I assume same as above?)
4. Pure compose view (no XML) in activity/fragment/custom view?

Answer (score 0):

For Fragments, you can use this strategy:

```
setViewCompositionStrategy(
        ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
)
```

According to [this document](https://www.kodeco.com/31473074-interoperability-with-jetpack-compose), you can use below strategy for Activities:

```
setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnDetachedFromWindow)
```